# Need to retrieve value from Get method

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, http-post, http-get

I am doing project in Spring. After some transaction in payment gateway, the control enters into POST method, **but I need GET method meant for display in html file.**
Below is my code where control enters after the payment gateway as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receive",method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String afterPaymentReceive(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(required=false) String eTransactionId,@RequestParam(required=false) String msg){

..................
..................

return "static/html/success";
}
```

I am having **viewResolver for html files** only. so I need to display success.html.

But below error shows in browser.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported 
type Status report message 
Request method 'POST' not supported
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Any way to solve this. Alternate way also warmly welcome. Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: You may want to set `value = "eTransactionId"` and `value = "msg"` in the respective `@RequestParam` declarations.  I think value defaults to "" so probably Spring can't match this controller method.

Comment: Judging from the exception you are POSTing instead of GETting from a form.

Comment: @Rajit, I hope that is not the error, bcoz I ve checked the variable correctly only assigned.

Comment: @M. Deinum,  after payment gateway the control goes to only POST method due to security reason. But I need to convert Post to get method to display in html

Comment: My mistake, Spring automatically uses the name of the variable